# How do I access specific elements in JSON through Jinja2

Tags: python, json, flask, jinja2

I'm currently using python to retrieve data from an Azure Active Directory through the Microsoft Graph API:

**Result**

[image]

Now what I need to do is, use this data to display it in a better way (more readable), for example display each attribute of each active directory object in a neat way, something like this:

[image]

You will see in my code that the function that gives me the json data is:

`graph_data = requests.get(endpoint, headers=http_headers, stream=False).json()`

**CODE**

config.py

```
RESOURCE = "https://graph.microsoft.com"  # Add the resource you want the access token for
TENANT = "joanperez5hotmail.onmicrosoft.com";
AUTHORITY_HOST_URL = "https://login.microsoftonline.com"
CLIENT_ID = "HERE I WROTE MY CLIENT ID";
CLIENT_SECRET = "HERE I WROTE MY CLIENT SECRET";

# These settings are for the Microsoft Graph API Call
API_VERSION = 'v1.0'
```

app.py

```
import adal
import flask #web framework
import uuid
import requests

import config

app = flask.Flask(__name__)
app.debug = True
app.secret_key = 'development'

PORT = 5000  # A flask app by default runs on PORT 5000
AUTHORITY_URL = config.AUTHORITY_HOST_URL + '/' + config.TENANT
REDIRECT_URI = 'http://localhost:{}/getAToken'.format(PORT)
TEMPLATE_AUTHZ_URL = ('https://login.microsoftonline.com/{}/oauth2/authorize?' +
                      'response_type=code&client_id={}&redirect_uri={}&' +
                      'state={}&resource={}')


@app.route("/")
def main():
    login_url = 'http://localhost:{}/login'.format(PORT)
    resp = flask.Response(status=307)
    resp.headers['location'] = login_url
    return resp


@app.route("/login")
def login():
    auth_state = str(uuid.uuid4())
    flask.session['state'] = auth_state
    authorization_url = TEMPLATE_AUTHZ_URL.format(
        config.TENANT,
        config.CLIENT_ID,
        REDIRECT_URI,
        auth_state,
        config.RESOURCE)
    resp = flask.Response(status=307)
    resp.headers['location'] = authorization_url
    return resp


@app.route("/getAToken")
def main_logic():
    code = flask.request.args['code']
    state = flask.request.args['state']
    if state != flask.session['state']:
        raise ValueError("State does not match")
    auth_context = adal.AuthenticationContext(AUTHORITY_URL)
    token_response = auth_context.acquire_token_with_authorization_code(code, REDIRECT_URI, config.RESOURCE,
                                                                        config.CLIENT_ID, config.CLIENT_SECRET)
    # It is recommended to save this to a database when using a production app.
    flask.session['access_token'] = token_response['accessToken']

    return flask.redirect('/graphcall')


@app.route('/graphcall')
def graphcall():
    if 'access_token' not in flask.session:
        return flask.redirect(flask.url_for('login'))
    endpoint = config.RESOURCE + '/' + config.API_VERSION + '/groups/' #https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/groups/
    http_headers = {'Authorization': flask.session.get('access_token'),
                    'User-Agent': 'adal-python-sample',
                    'Accept': 'application/json',
                    'Content-Type': 'application/json',
                    'client-request-id': str(uuid.uuid4())}
    graph_data = requests.get(endpoint, headers=http_headers, stream=False).json()
    return flask.render_template('homePage.html', graph_data=graph_data)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run()
```

**EDIT**

Adding question from comment: How do I access each specific element in Jinja?

Comment: So, you want to format it like the 2nd image? Build your html and that will do it for you.

Comment: @CodeLikeBeaker hmm yea! But the thing is that I dont know how would i access each part of the data, for example, for the column display name, i would need to see just staff and interns. How would i access to that soecific portion to display it per row in a html table

Comment: Take a look at jinja2: https://realpython.com/primer-on-jinja-templating/

Comment: @CodeLikeBeaker oh is that how I embed Python in html?

Comment: It's one way. There are several, but I personally use jinja2

Comment: @CodeLikeBreaker oh great, hmm but my doubt is still like, how would i access each specific element like for example, if i just wanna retrieve the display name, instead of all that bunch of code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To answer your comment question, "How would I access each specific element" you can do something like this as an example.

```
my_data = [{'id': 1, 'name': 'Frank'}, {'id': 2, 'name': 'Rakesh'}]
```

This would then be returned in your `render_template` in flask (which I can see by your code, you are already doing)

In your Jinja template you would do something like this:

```
<table>
    {% for md in my_data %}
        <tr>
            <td>{{ md.id }}</td><td>{{ md.name }}</td>
        </tr>
    {% endfor %}
</table>
```

This should get you going in the right direction. Anything beyond that you will have to do some research on [Jinja2](http://jinja.pocoo.org/docs/2.10/templates/) and how it works.